# PWA storage reset after restart iOS 16.6.1 (20G81)

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

When re-instelling my PWA in order to see effect of changes made to my updated manifest the PWA stopped saving cookies and localstorage data when hard closing the app and restarting it.

I decided to revert all changes made to the manifest and other stuff like service workers.

When removing the PWA and re-adding it to the Home Screen as apple calls it, the problem persisted. No cookies or localstorage were saved when hard restarting the app.

The next thing I did was testing it on an other phone eventually the same hardware with another iOS version though, no problems at all everything worked as it is supposed to

After that I restarted my phone before eventually updating the software on it.

To my surprise the reboot with a fresh installation of the PWA worked.

Could anyone light me up on this one… how was I able to trigger this strange behavior? Did the first instance of the long lived PWA somehow saturated some resource caps which prevented every new instance to save any form of data? What would be the best practices in that case in order to prevent that behavior in the future?